# How to fix 'name 'csrf' is not defined' error in Django

Tags: python, django

I took this code in the WEB but it was for Django 1.9. I'm using 2.1 in my project.

I import this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, reverse
from django.views import View
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import ContactForm
from blog import settings

class EContactsView(View):
    template_name = 'home/contacts.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    context['contact_form'] = ContactForm()

    return render_to_response(template_name=self.template_name, context=context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}

    form = ContactForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        email_subject = 'EVILEG :: Сообщение через контактную форму '
        email_body = "С сайта отправлено новое сообщение\n\n" \
                     "Имя отправителя: %s \n" \
                     "E-mail отправителя: %s \n\n" \
                     "Сообщение: \n" \
                     "%s " % \
                     (form.cleaned_data['name'], form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['message'])

        send_mail(email_subject, email_body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['target_email@example.com'], fail_silently=False)

    return render_to_response(template_name=self.template_name, context=context)
```

name 'csrf' is not defined / traceback:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQadA.png)

Comment: can you add contact.html?

Comment: It makes no difference what Django version you use, it is a basic Python requirement that before you use something you have to define it or import it from the place it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `render_to_response`. It was obsolete, even in Django 1.9.

Use `render` instead. Then you don't have to do anything in the view to handle csrf protection.

Change the import to

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Change the `get` method to:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    context['contact_form'] = ContactForm()
    return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context=context)
```

and the final line of the `post` method to:

```
return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context=context)
```

Finally, you might prefer to use `FormView` here. The [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) is for a contact form.

Comment: Thanx. But now I have small problem with this line:

Comment: context['contact_form'] = ContactForm()

Comment: NameError: name 'context' is not defined

Comment: You still need `context = {}`, or replace the two lines with `context = {'contact_form': ContactForm()}`.